# Accessing css with asset() in laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-package

Eghad, the laravel documentation is lacking. So if you want to have css in a package for the package views specifically, and you figure out how to publish those assets, how do you specify the path when calling them with the asset() helper?

e.g.:

I have a packages with a resources/assets/css/mystyles.css
I tell the Service Provider to publish my assets under 'vendor/myorg/mypackage'

```
// Publishing assets.
$this->publishes([
    __DIR__.'/../resources/assets' => public_path('vendor/myorg/mypackage'),
], 'mypackage.assets');
```

I have a view in my package where I want it to display that css, what do I put in the asset() call? 'css/mystyles.css'? 'vendor/myorg/mypackage/css/mystyles.css'?  something even more convoluted?

```
<link href="{{ asset('????/css/mystyles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: I think it should be, `<link href="{{ asset('vendor/myorg/mypackage/css/mystyles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: I keep seeing my ad-hoc replacement for the css sheet name 'mystyles' out of the corner of my eye and thinking it reads 'mystery styles'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [here](https://laravelpackage.com/09-routing.html#assets)

Your package user must publish your assets. They will be placed at (in your case) to `vendor/myorg/mypackage` - you specify that patch at provider.

After publishing you can reach asset by `asset('vendor/myorg/mypackage/css/mystyles.css')`

Comment: thanks, I figured that out with some tinkering after posting but still wasn't sure that was the best-practices method.

Answer (score -1):

helper function `asset()` points to the public folder in Laravel directories, you can move your stylesheet files to the public directory and by helper `asset()` access any style file you want